# Would this workout work for making my butt round and toned?

Tags: workout-routines, toning

I posted a question before about how I can fix an uneven butt and I found a workout online and I was wondering if it would help. Here it is:

- 30 jumping jacks
- 20 lunges
- 10 squats
- 10 plié squats
- 20 side lunges
- 20 glute kickbacks
- 15 short bridges
- 10 side leg circles (each)
- 20 glute kickbacks
- 15 squats
- 10 plié squats
- 20 jumping jacks

Would this work to even it out, but still continue to round and tone?

Answer (score 1):

Your workout sounds alright, or maybe even excessive depending on how you do it. (Make sure it is 'hard', not easy.)

Also watch your diet. Where your fat goes to is dependent on your genes; to you the excess fat may go straight to your rearend (assuming that you're unhappy with just your rearend, hence your question).

'Will it even work out?'
Hard to say because it really depends on your consistency and efforts.

Comment: How do you think it can be made harder? Would you like to give any directions towards it?

Comment: It can be made 'harder' by increasing the resistance. You can get more resistance by say, doing the exercise slower, increasing the weight.

Comment: Edited your answer - Please refrain from vernacular, as some people may find it offensive.

Answer (score -1):

That isn't a bad workout per se, but there's a lot in it that won't specifically do anything for your bottom.  For example, jumping-jacks are cardio, with some leg and core-muscle elements.  That isn't to say they shouldn't be in your workout; just that they're not directly addressing the problem you've asked about.

Besides whole-body exercises like swimming, climbing, hiking, running, etc. that use your body-weight to tone and strengthen major muscle-groups (including the legs, hips and glutes), the single best exercise I know of for rear ends -- especially to "lift" and round out the appearance of them -- is kettlebells.

There are many things you can do with a kettlebell, but the one that really works your lower-back, glutes, and the rear tops of your thighs -- the muscles that form and "hold up" your buttocks -- is the kettlebell swing.  [Here's a video describing the form](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0jalJ-3e7U) -- there are many more out there.  This is also a good calorie-burner exercise (due to using large muscle-groups and a whole-body motion), so don't be afraid to use light weights and do a lot of reps if you're looking to burn fat.  (Though of course, the best way to lose fat is to improve your diet; but that's another topic. ;)  Do make sure your kettlebell isn't too heavy, since you can hurt your back -- it's better to start small.  Mine is 20lb and I'm very fit, but I doubt I'll ever need a bigger one.

Regarding unevenness, the best way to address that is to focus on an exercise that forces you to use both sides evenly.  (Just be aware that your weaker side is going to be more sore at first, and make sure you don't overdo it in the beginning.)  Kettlebell swings, done properly with good form, would be great for that.

Comment: So...out of a pyramid workout of squats, lunges, plies (A type of squat) and kickbacks, you invalidate it all because they do jumping jacks?

Comment: I believe I did not invalidate it all, but rather referred to jumping-jacks as an example of one exercise that does not target the desired muscles, and then offered suggestions for some that do.  Sorry it wasn't clear.